# Iphone 5 game resolution

Tags: iphone, resolution, iphone-5

I have a developer working on a game for me for ios for iPhone 5. He stated the resolution we must use for the game is 320 x 568, but the iphone 5 has a resolution of 640 x 1136 and he stated that this is the resolution for the graphics and not the game leveling design. The game is a 2D maze game.

I am still learning, so any help would be greatly appreciated. Which resolution is the correct resolution? Why is it half of what apple states?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Take a look here http://forum.unity3d.com/threads/150981-1136x640-iPhone-5-Resolution

Comment: Thanks Amiya, i read through that. Does this mean that we should design for 320 x 568 and use the scaling? Wouldnt that expand the graphics?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the story.  When Apple introduced the iPhone 4, it introduced the "Retina Display".  That is, the iPhone 4 had a screen with twice as many pixels on it than the previous iPhones.  So to compensate, Apple came up with the screen points system.  It works like this:

-On non-retina devices, 1 point = 1 pixel
-On retina devices, 1 point = 2 pixels

-On any device, the programmer's coordinates are done in points.
-On any device, the art assets should be done using pixels

Example: I have a 200x200 pixel image used on retina devices.  When I load the image into a view, the size of the view is 100x100 points.

In order to make sure your image is loaded properly, you have to use the @2x suffix.  If you have a 200x200 pixel image "myImage.png", it will be loaded as 200x200 points and will be scaled up on retina devices.  If instead you name the image "myImage@2x.png", instead it will interpret the image as 100x100 points, and will scaled down on non-retina devices.  You can also have two versions of an image (Apple recommends 2 images although it isn't strictly necessary).  If you have both 100x100 pixel "myImage.png" and 200x200 pixel "myImage@2x.png", it will interpret them as two versions of the same image, and will use the @2x one on retina devices and the other one on non-retina devices.  In both cases, the image will be interpreted as 100x100 points.

You might also want to take a look at [Apple's High Resolution Guide](https://developer.apple.com/high-resolution/).